# React.memo() gave me the error (0 , _components_ComponentName_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-hooks

The example code is here:

```
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import { memo } from 'react';

function PokemonBriefCard(props) {

  return (
    <div>Some random component</div>
  );
}

export default memo(PokemonBriefCard);
// export default PokemonBriefCard;
```

The usage of that component is the following:

```
          <div className="card-brief-container">
            {
              pokemonList.map((pokemon, index) => 
              <div key={index}>
                {PokemonBriefCard({
                  ...pokemon,
                  action: pokemon.favourite ? removeFav : addFav
                })}
              </div>
              )
            }
          </div>
```

It seems that if I put `memo` to the component, it would throw an error like this:

[image: Error Message]

And once I remove the `memo` (like using the `export default PokemonBriefCard` instead), the project would render without an issue.

Am I using `React.memo` in the wrong way? I read through the introduction doc but can't find the cause of it.

Comment: Your code snippet is correct.

Comment: @Anshu But I am still getting this error. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you use ```PokemonBriefCard``` ?

Comment: @OktayYuzcan Thanks for noting, just added the usage to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`React.memo` is used for components. If `PokemonBriefCard` is a component, you should not call it as function

```
 PokemonBriefCard({   // this is wrong
     ...pokemon,
     action: pokemon.favourite ? removeFav : addFav
 })
```

You should use it as a component: `<PokemonBriefCard ... />`

If it is just a render function `PokemonBriefCard(...)` (better make the name camel case), then you can't use `React.memo`, since it is used only on components.

Note: `React.memo` does not return function, this is why the error tells you it **is not a function**